# Hardcode or Plist, Which should I follow to display data in UITextView?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am writing code to put a label, image and description on a view. The label and image are working but i don't know how and where to write code for my description details. For e.g When a user taps in university, I have a UITextView where the description suppose to appear but have no idea. Please can someone help me out with a detailed way to sort this out???

Answer (score 0):

Plists are for properties and they’re difficult (as in slow) to parse, so maybe you’d like to use flat files, Core Data or other means.  If it’s guaranteed not to change (though this might never be the case) then I think using localized hard-coded strings could work.